# Ubuntu has two kernels in /boot

Tags: 12.04, boot, kernel

my server running Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS has two kernel images in /boot
at the moment 3.11.0-19 and 3.2.0-60
And every time i do a dist-upgrade the both get updated.
Is this necessary or how can i remove the "oldest" one?

as Nux said i've removed older kernels. now it shows:

dpkg --list | grep linux-image
linux-image-3.11.0-20-generic              3.11.0-20.34~precise1
Linux kernel image for version 3.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-3.2.0-54-generic               3.2.0-54.82
Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-generic-lts-saucy              3.11.0.20.18
Generic Linux kernel image

and uname -r still says 3.2.0-54
why not 3.11.0-20 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can know what version you are using :

```
uname -r
```

To remove old kernels just follow this answer :

[How to remove old kernels](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-or-hide-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu-or-free-sp)

Comment: it's not old kernels as in grub boot loader. it's just 2 separate kernels. not sequential.    
uname -r gives 3.2.0-54    
which makes it even stranger to me!

Comment: you can follow that answer and remove the old kernel

Comment: which should i remove than? everything older than 3.2.0-54? or older than 3.2.0-60 or older than 3.11.0-19?

Comment: older than 3.2.0-54

Comment: i've updated the question. with feedback

Comment: Okey Solved.. this is one of the reasons to reboot a linux distro! now uname -r shows the correct value.. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is good practice to keep at least one working ("old") kernel in /boot. Otherwise, if a new kernel displays issues (which might even be Linux not booting at all), the repair procedure gets unnecessarily complicated.